# Align divs vertically when floated

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

with a floated set of divs how do i vertically align them so they sit all together without white space below shorter divs ie here....

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .imadiv {
                border: 1px solid #FF0000;
                float: left;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 200px;
            }
            #wrapper {
                width:800px;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="one" class="imadiv">
                <p>div1</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus ipsum, ultrices eget nibh et, auctor tristique quam. Nullam blandit.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="two" class="imadiv">
                <p>div2</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Nullam blandit.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="three" class="imadiv">
                <p>div3</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus ipsum, ultrices eget nibh et, auctor tristique quam. Nullam blandit.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="four" class="imadiv">
                <p>div4
                    </p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus ipsum, ultrices eget nibh et, auctor tristique quam. Nullam blandit.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="five" class="imadiv">
                <p>div5
                    </p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus ipsum, ultrices eget nibh et, auctor tristique quam. Nullam blandit. Donec risus ipsum, ultrices eget nibh et.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="six" class="imadiv">
                <p>div6
                    </p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus ipsum, ultrices eget nibh et, auctor tristique quam. Nullam blandit. Donec risus ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus ipsum, ultrices eget nibh et.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AK32q/4/

so that div5 butts up to div 2 vertically im sure it's Jquery but i cant find anything?

many thanks

Comment: looks like the layout you are using does not need to use `float`, just a table layout is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your class `.imadiv` a `min-height` see updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/AK32q/3/

CSS:

```
.imadiv {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height:200px;
}
```

That just makes it all lined up with same height. I'm sure that's not what you want.

But there's a plugin by David DeSandro, I use his masonry plugin http://masonry.desandro.com/

See your fiddle with his plugin here http://jsfiddle.net/AK32q/5/

Jquery:

```
var $container = $('#wrapper');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: 30,
  itemSelector: '.imadiv'
});

var msnry = $container.data('masonry');
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

try giving the div inside the list like `<li><div id="#"></div></li>` , this is will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the top row only, repeat for bottom row.

```
var element = document.getElementById('one'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    one = style.getPropertyValue('height');

var element = document.getElementById('two'),
    style2 = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    two = style2.getPropertyValue('height');

var element = document.getElementById('three'),
    style3 = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    three = style3.getPropertyValue('height');

one = parseInt(one);
two = parseInt(two);
three = parseInt(three);
var divmax = Math.max(one,two,three);
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = divmax;
document.getElementById('one').style.height = divmax + "px";
document.getElementById('two').style.height = divmax + "px";
document.getElementById('three').style.height = divmax + "px";
```

[FIDDLE DIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AK32q/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any third party frameworks/ libraries. You can do this with pure CSS. All you need to do is use a combination of `unordered lists` and `absolute positioning`. That would give you the exact effect you are look for.

Considering the structure of the html the way you have provided, this following CSS should do the trick for you:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

ul {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:10px;
    width:30%;
    position:absolute;
}

ul.first {
    left:0%;
}

ul.second {
    left:33%;
}

ul.third {
    left:66%;
}

ul li {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:Orange;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/3s4Xj/1/

This is a very simple layout that you desire. I'd recommend using pure CSS instead of any third-party libraries.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Excellent even better what about older browsers with this method?